# In-App Update install always failed with error code -100 in Android

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update, in-app-update, google-play-core

I've implemented [in-app update](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) in my Android Application with FLEXIBLE update flow. I'm checking and requesting for the update in onCreate() of MainActivity

While updating the app, always install failed with error code `-100` which is mentioned at [ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode.html#ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR) . Can anyone help me to solve this

```
val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
appUpdateManager.registerListener { state ->
    if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.FAILED) {
        Log.e("::MG::", "appUpdateManager:Status.FAILED")
        Log.e("::MG::", "appUpdateManager:ErrorCode:"+state.installErrorCode())
    }

    if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
        //sBR(mainhell, resources.getString(R.string.exit))
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
            mainhell,
            "Update has been downloaded. \nDo you want to install?",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        )
            .setAction("INSTALL") {
                //If Downloaded Install Update
                val i = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                finish()
                startActivity(i)
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate()
            }
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
        snackbar.show()

    }
}

val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    when {
        appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE &&
                appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
        -> {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
                    this,
                    FLEXIBLE_UPDATE
                )
        }
        appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED -> {
            if (appUpdateManager != null) {
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcate

> ```
> E/::MG::: appUpdateManager:InstallStatus.FAILED 
> E/::MG::: appUpdateManager:installErrorCode:-100
> ```

Comment: I am facing the same issue if you get a solution, please help!

Comment: did u find the solution please share

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but got this and managed to fix it : errcode -100 happens when you try to upgrade to a release apk from a debug one. It will not allow it.

This can happen if you're under a debug mode while developing, and trying to update to an APK published with release flag on the Play Store.

Solution is simply to use same targets release<->release apks update, or debug<-> debug ones (which may not be possible if your app store APK is a release one).

Comment: not working for me.if found out something else please share